# Importing a txt file into SQL Server with a where clause

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2012, where-clause, flat-file

I have a `.txt` file which is 6.00 GB. It is a tab-delimited file so when I try to load it into SQL Server, the column delimiter is tab.

I need to load that `.txt` file into the database, but I don't need all the rows from the 6.00 Gb file. I need to be able to use a condition like

```
select * 
into <my table> 
where column5 in ('ab, 'cd')
```

but this is a text file and am not able to load it into db with that condition.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: No, you cannot do this natively in SQL Server

Comment: Will you be importing *most* of the rows from the flat file or just a very few? Is the condition you're searching for something that you could do very easily, like with [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)? If so, you can filter your data before importing it. Otherwise, you're probably going to have to import the entire file, then run a `DELETE FROM`... `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Thank you BOB, I will be importing around 20% of the file, the thing is when I do a preview on the flat file the default column name (column 11) is the one that I need to put condition on.  that colmn has around 65 distinct names and I need to filter by 2 names. Can I try using visual studio or any other tool.?

Comment: I've never used this particular tool, but a quick Google search on `windows tool text search` yielded [WinGREP](http://www.wingrep.com/) which may be a quick solution for you.

Comment: hey I think i found a way, there is a similar command like grep in windows called findstr, when i gave that command for the txt file it shows all the rows which i need for that name, all i need is to store the output in a separate text file. any ideas on it.?

Comment: Thank you so much bob, for giving me the idea about grep, it worked i ran that command and stored it in a separate txt file and I am able to import that into my db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with BULK INSERT command? Take a look at this solution:

```
--Create temporary table
CREATE TABLE #BulkTemporary
(
  Id int,
  Value varchar(10)
)

--BULK INSERT has no WHERE clause
BULK INSERT #BulkTemporary FROM 'D:\Temp\File.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

--Filter results
SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM #BulkTemporary WHERE Value IN ('Row2', 'Row3')

--Drop temporary table
DROP TABLE #BulkTemporary
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a Bulk Insert into a staging table and form there move the data you actually want into a production table.  The Where Clause is for doing something based on a specific condition inside SQL Server, not for loading data into SQL Server.