# Need to Bulk Copy records from csv file to table

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to bulk copy the below records from .csv file to 3 different tables based on first field . I need to use Bulk Insert in SQL server for doing it. Also I am not sure of final record as the count of records will change (header and trailer will be same). Please assist. I have tried with Bulk Insert but it fails as the header and trailer have different columns

---

01,EMP,5,06-16-2018 --header
02,06-16-2018,06-16-2018,100,SMF,Debit,KK
02,06-16-2018,06-16-2018,100,LKX,Encash,SS

### 03,2,200 -- trailer

If 01 then copy to header table, If 02 then copy to emp table
If 03 then trailer table

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your question so that it'd be possible to understand the structure of 01,02 and 03?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try the approach from the [Importing a txt file into SQL Server with a where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359961/importing-a-txt-file-into-sql-server-with-a-where-clause)?

It says that you should create a temporary table and after bulk insert into this table you would be able to make some conditional inserts in your real tables. This approach implies that the structure of your 01, 02 and 03 records should be more or less the same, though.